# how to grep from multiple file and out to a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have 3 files in the same location with below information:

`File1: msisdn, channel, transid, time1`

`File2: transid, time2, messageid`

`File3: messageid, status, time3, time4`

How can I grep from 3 files and write into a text file in below format:

```
msisdn|channel|transid|message|status|time1|time2|duration1(time2-time1)|time3|time4|duration2(time4-time3)
```

Comment: `grep` is used to find lines based on a regexp/string. What is your condition? Show us brief examples of the actual files, too. Do this by editing your question, not by commenting.

Answer (score 0):

A series of commands can be placed in a `BASH` file to accomplish what you are suggesting here. Since your selection of criteria seems very custom and does not follow an obvious logic, you will likely have to explicitly store each variable. Here is an example assuming that File1 literally contains a text file with a single line that looks something like this:

```
123456789, 1, 10, 12345
```

which corresponds to msisdn, channel, transid, time1, etc. separated by commas. An example of how you could grab the values you want in a `BASH` script using `awk` (`grep` is not particularly useful here), is as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Define the filenames
File1='filename_of_file1.txt'
File2='filename_of_file2.txt'
File3='filename_of_file3.txt'
OutputFile='filename_of_output_file.txt'

# Grab the Nth column in each respective file
msisdn=$(awk -F, '{print $1}' $File1
channel=$(awk -F, '{print $2}' $File1
transid1=$(awk -F, '{print $3}' $File1
time1=$(awk -F, '{print $4}' $File1
transid2=$(awk -F, '{print $1}' $File2
...
...

# Calculate the difference between certain variables
duration1=$(echo ${time2}-${time1} | bc)
duration2=$(echo ${time4}-${time3} | bc)
...
...

# Return the formatted string to an output file
echo "${msisdn}|${channel}|${transid}..." > $OutputFile
```

This is obviously incomplete (all sections labelled with `...`). However, it should at least show a template of how one would potentially approach this problem in a very explicit and specific manner.